# Connecting Asp.net web api hosted on AWS EC2 to AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway

I am creating a rest api using AWS API Gateway and ASP.Net Web Api as the backend service. I have created an ASP.Net Web Api application and hosted it on AWS EC2 instance. Now I want to connect this api hosted on EC2 to the AWS API Gateway.

I searched on internet a lot but found no examples for API gateway with EC2. All the examples are either for Lamda or for HTTP proxy.

Answer (score 1):

There is no special EC2 integration with API Gateway. You should use the same instructions for building an HTTP integration, just specifying the address of your EC2 instance as the integration endpoint.

**NOTE:** You may want to consider using some additional components like Elastic Load Balancing (ELB) and/or Elastic Beanstalk to improve reliability of your integration backend.